# Publishing an application with an account login, but without registration, in the App Store

Tags: ios, authentication, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have created an app for my company. To use the application, you need to log in to the account that We ourselves create for each specific employee, registration of new accounts in the application is not available now and will not be available in the future, since only We can create new accounts for new employees and delete old accounts on our server .
Can such an application be published in the App Store, given the new requirements of Apple?
Is there any way to avoid this? Maybe if our application is unlisted, then it will be allowed to be published without explicitly registering new accounts?

We tried to submit our app for review and provided a demo account, but we were denied publishing due to implicit registration in the app.

Comment: It probably isn't the lack of use registration, but rather that your app is for a limited audience.  An unlisted or custom app may be what you need. Unlisted apps are good for a situation where the app is not generally applicable and is for use by users on their own, unmanaged, devices. Custom app distribution is good where the devices are owned and/or managed by the company.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the lack of user registration that is causing your app rejection.

For an App to be made available in the App Store it needs to be applicable to a broad audience. It sounds like your app is only for a very limited set of users; employees of your company.

For these types of apps you can use [custom app distribution](https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/) or [unlisted app distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/).

Custom app distribution works well when an app needs to be made available to one or more organisations who manage their devices. (You can use it with unmanaged devices, but distribution is more complex).

In your case, it sounds like an unlisted app would be the best approach.

In both cases you still go through app review and will need to provide a demo login.

A third possible approach is to use an Enterprise developer program. Due to abuse in the past, Apple discourages these now that custom and unlisted app distribution is available. Enterprise programs are more expensive and are not granted to smaller companies.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can create test account from your backend and provide this account authorisation info to the apple review team, so they can authorise and test your application

Comment: Yes, We tried, We provided them with a test account to sign in to the app, but they still said registration should be explicit.